# Использование else совместно с внутренним и внешнем if

Tags: java

Почему если написать вот так:

```
if (true) {
    System.out.println("Вика");
    if (true) {
        System.out.println("Инна");
        if (false) {
            System.out.println("Маша");
        }
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Леонид");
}
```

Выводит "Вика" и "Инна"

А вот так:

```
if (true) {
    System.out.println("Вика");
    if (true) {
        System.out.println("Инна");
        if (false) {
            System.out.println("Маша");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Леонид");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Оба варианта правильные. Какой из них использовать - зависит от конкретной ситуации. Откуда вы взяли информацию, что первый - неправильный?

Comment: У вас 2 разных ветвления получается. В первом случае Else относится к одному if, а во втором случае Else относится к другому if.

Comment: Оба варианта неправильные: `if(true)` и `if(false)` — бесполезные конструкции. Обе нужно удалить, вторую еще и со всем блоком. Для того чтобы можно было ответить на вопрос, распишите подробно чего Вы хотите добиться и почему Вы считаете что первый вариант криво работает.

Comment: Всё спасибо, понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для оператора `else` нет внутреннего и внешнего `if`. Конструкция в общем виде выглядит

```
if (условие) {блок кода если условие == true} else {блок кода если условие == false}
```

Каждому `else`сопоставляется конкретный `if`.  Сами блоки кода `{какой то код}` могут содержать свои управляющие конструкции, циклы, методы, что угодно, это не должно вводить вас в заблуждение.

В первом случае вы сопоставляете `else` самому первому `if`

```
if (true) {что то про женские имена} else {Леонид}
```

т.к. условие выполнено, то выполняется блок кода про женские имена, а блок кода следом за `else` не выполняется.
Во втором случае вы сопоставляете `else` самому последнему `if`

```
if (false) {Маша} else {Леонид}
```

Программа доходить до этого оператора и условие не выполняется, соответственно выполняется блок кода следующий за `else` и мы видим Леонида.


**Как резюме:** обе конструкции работают правильно с той логикой, с которой вы их записали для машины. При сложных конструкциях надо следить что куда относиться. Для подобных многоярусных ветвлений часто бывают полезны конструкции типа

```
if() {}
else if() {}
else if() {}
и т.д.
```

или оператор `switch`